# Please explain the terms line voltage, phase voltage, line current and phase current in a 3-phase circuit

Tags: ac, three-phase

I have searched online for an explanation of these terms and was unable to find a clear enough one. Request you to explain with reference to the images below:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Any decent electrical textbook, and many sources on the web...

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE. It would take a book to explain all the details, so the up-front answer is to read books on 3-phase, plus what is on the web. @Andyaka has a good summary below in his answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Phase voltage is between A and N (or B/C and N). Also a to N or b/c to N.
- Line voltage is between any two of the three feed lines (ignoring N if present)
- Line current flows down any line between source and load (ignoring N if present)
- Phase current is the current in any load element whether star or delta